# Jquery dialogbox appears with empty content

Tags: jquery

I'm facing a problem with jquery dialog.

```
<div id="mycontent" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      hello brother
</div>

<a class="btn" data-target="#mycontent" data-toggle="modal">Open Modal</a>
```

i have no problem with above calling method (with a tag) and my dialogbox appears good and im seeing #mycontent div inside dialogbox.

But, dialogbox is appears empty when i calling as below (i cant see #mycontent div inside dialogbox)

```
<div id="mycontent" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
          hello brother
    </div>

<a class="btn" onclick="showDialog()">Open Modal</a>

<script>

     $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#mycontent').dialog({

             autoOpen:false,
             width:500,
             height:500,
});
})

      function showDialog({
           $('#mycontent').dialog('open');
      })
</script>
```

Why empty dialogbox appears?

Thanks inadvance

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

Error in you `showDialog()` function

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mycontent').dialog({
        autoOpen:false,
        width:500,
        height:500,
    });
});

function showDialog(){
    $('#mycontent').dialog('open');
};
</script>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/k82bf5Lh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is weird, and not working.
Try somthing like this, and please read the bootstrap docs how to make a modal:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

html

```
<div id="mycontent"class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Hello brother;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<a class="btn">Open Modal</a>
```

jquery

```
var showDialog = function()
{
   $('#mycontent').modal('show');
}

 $('.btn').click(showDialog);
```

Link to JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/fx8b0o9q/

Answer (score 0):

ThIS MIGHT WORK FOR YOU

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
           $('#mycontent').dialog({
             autoOpen:false,
             width:500,
             height:500,
});
});

      function showDialog(){
           $('#mycontent').dialog('open');
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="mycontent" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
          hello brother
    </div>

<a class="btn" onclick="showDialog()">Open Modal</a>
```